# How to customize which camera app is launched when double tapping the power button?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, camera, customization, lineageos

I have a Galaxy S7 Edge with the latest lineage nightly. How to customize which camera app to launch when double pressing the power button? The original one causes issues for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defualt camera app will be opened by double tapping power button. To set the app as default camera

1. Clear deaults of the stock and desired camera app. This can be done in app info.
2. Double tap the power button twice
3. It should pop up a dialog with a list of installed camera apps. Choose your app and click always.